# Am I eligible for a CDC/504 loan as a sole proprietor?

Tags: united-states, loans, small-business, sole-proprietorship

I have a sole proprietor software consultant business, and I am thinking of buying a small office because it would be a better investment than my current office rental.  I was looking into loans for small businesses and found the CDC/504 loan.

The sba.gov web pages say "Generally, your business must create or retain one job for every $65,000 provided by the SBA".  However, I do not plan on hiring employees in the foreseeable future.  Do I count as one retained employee?  Or as the proprietor, don't I count?

References:

- https://www.sba.gov/loans-grants/see-what-sba-offers/sba-loan-programs/real-estate-equipment-loans-cdc-504/cdc-504-loan-amounts-interest-rates-fees
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBA_504_Loan

Comment: Are you aware of the [Freelancing](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/) and [Startups](http://startups.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange sites?

Comment: @BenMiller No I am not.  However, I'm not technically a startup because I've been in business for 2 years.  Should I move this to the freelancer section?

Comment: You can wait to see what the response is here, if you like.  However, you might get a better response on one of those other sites, as this site is focused on *personal* finance, and business-related questions are not as accepted.